# JQuery get indeces of multiple columns regarding to class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such table

```
<table id="myTable">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td class="class1">aaa</td>
    <td class="class1">bbb</td>
    <td class="class1">ccc</td>

    <td class="class2">ddd</td>
    <td class="class2">eee</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="class1">fff</td>
    <td class="class1">ggg</td>
    <td class="class1">hhh</td>

    <td class="class2">iii</td>
    <td class="class2">jjj</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to give **class name**, and get the **columns' indices**, which has that class name.
For example I give "class 2" and get 3 and 4.
I tried this. But [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/) gives me the last column's index number.

```
 var indices = $("#myTable tbody tr").first().children("td.class2").index();
```

I need an array that includes all index values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.each()`.

```
var indices = [];
$("#myTable tbody tr").first().children("td.class2").each(function(){
    indices.push($(this).index());
});
// indices = [3, 4]
```

In modern web browsers you can use `Array#map`.

```
var indices = $("#myTable tbody tr").first().children("td.class2").get().map(function(self){
    return $(self).index();
});
```

Comment: There is no real need in using `Array.map` when jQuery has good cross-browser solution.

Comment: @VisioN, disagree. There is a need to know that these functions are available natively

Answer (score 4):

You can use `map()` and `index()` methods:

```
var indices = $("#myTable tr:first td.class2").map(function(i) {
    return $(this).index();
}).get();

console.log(indices); // [3, 4]
```

Comment: Being pedantic, `.map()` should return a jQuery object

Comment: @Alexander while `get()` returns native JS array out of it.

Comment: @VisioN, I know. But, my statement is still valid